# Can I have a generalized form to acces to any e-mail server using JavaMail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I' ve seen a lot of examples for accesing to an email account, also downloading attachments, but, most of them works with gmail.

I'm looking for a generalized form to access to most of e-mail providers.

for example

I'm thinking that I can imagine the server, like email@emailserver.com

```
user = "email@emailserver.com"
password = "hispass"
server = "pop.mailserver.com"

store.connect(server, user, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to connect to any server, look at what Thunderbird asks for when configuring a new server.  Most of these configuration options will translate in a pretty straightforward way to JavaMail configuration.  Thunderbird also includes a bunch of "templates" for popular email service providers, to make setup easier.